# Dataset output is a list of index of a text sample. How can I draw my neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, training-data

It's my first time, so sorry if I do some error in formulating the question.

I've created a dataset to detect the position of error in some text comments. So, my dataset is composed like this:

[['Ogi', 'o', 'mangiato', 'una', 'mela', 'a', 'pranso', 'quanto'], [0], [1],[6,7]...]

How can I construct my neural network? How can I say: the output is not only a number, but it is a list?

Otherwise, how I can create my NN for detect type of spelling error?
I test also to create a dataset for multi-label classification, such as:
TEXT - class1 - class2 - class3 - etc. 
text - 0 - 1 - 0 - 1 etc.\

but it doesn't work: the accuracy or AUC is very low (like 0.10)

THANK YOU ALL!